# multiplying two nparray together python

Tags: python, numpy

What is an efficient way to multliply two numpy arrays together? For example, given

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

I want to calculate the dot product between A and B, which is

```
  A.B/|A||B| = (1*2 + 2*3 + .. 4*7)/sqrt(1^2 + 2^2... +4^2) * sqrt(.....)
```

How can I do this efficiently and fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using numpy, [numpy.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) would do the Job for you

```
numpy.dot(A,B)
51
```

---

The Fastest norm for a vector would be

```
n = math.sqrt(numpy.dot(A,A.conj()))
```

and here is the comparison with other methods

```
>>> t1=timeit.Timer("n = math.sqrt(numpy.dot(A,A.conj()))","from __main__ import A,math,numpy")
>>> t2=timeit.Timer("n = math.sqrt(sum(abs(A)**2))","from __main__ import A,math")
>>> t3=timeit.Timer("numpy.linalg.norm(A)","from __main__ import A,numpy")
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
2.82 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
13.16 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t3.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
15.68 usec/pass
>>>
```

Comment: is there a way to get the norm also (faster) :)

Comment: @Abhijit Isn't the second timeit cheating a bit since you are calling the python sum rather than the numpy one (and the abs)? How about `numpy.sqrt((numpy.abs(A)**2).sum())`? I'm surprised that `linalg.norm` turned out to be so slow though. I'm wondering if those timings would change as the length of the vectors got longer - may test it tomorrow or you can add it if you like.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), there is [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) which does what you are looking for:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm    
from numpy import dot

dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

I'm guessing that you want the sqrt of the sum of the squares, which is the default for `norm`. This metric is called the Frobenius norm or L2 norm. If you want a different metric, say the [Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) or L1 norm, it is simply a parameter to pass in.